# Iterate over two items in bash

Tags: bash, loops

Given a file `integers` that contains integers separated by new lines. For instance:

```
1
39
77
109
137
169
197
229
261
293
```

One can iterate over the file using the following code:

```
while read a
do
    echo "$a"
done < integers
```

I'm looking however for an elegant solution such that the loop takes two integers at once and always updates by one step, such that:

```
while #some funny commands
do
    echo "$a | $b"
done < integers
```

results in:

```
1 | 39
39 | 77
77 | 109
109 | 137
137 | 169
169 | 197
197 | 229
229 | 261
261 | 293
```

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/284187/bash-iterating-over-lines-in-a-variable

Comment: @AvinashBabu, @Jayesh: no that part already works. I want to iterate over a file such that in the `i`-th iteration `$a` contains the `i`-th line and `$b` the `i+1`-th line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{
    read a
    while read b; do
        echo "$a | $b"
        a=$b
    done
} < file
```

Output:

```
1 | 39
39 | 77
77 | 109
109 | 137
137 | 169
169 | 197
197 | 229
229 | 261
261 | 293
```

Comment: I thought the same, but both don't give expected output.

Comment: But then each iteration, two items are read. The intended program should print, in the `i`-th iteration, the `i`-th line and the `i+1`-th line.

Comment: @Kent The instruction `I'm looking however for an elegant solution such that the loop takes two integers at once and always updates by one step, such that` misled me.

Comment: Updated. And my answer doesn't need to have tests.

Answer (score 4):

Use a variable to store the previous value:

```
prev= 
while read line; do
   [[ ! -z $prev ]] && echo $prev "|" $line; 
   prev=$line; 
done <file
```